# PHP - use regex to change Array Key based on Values

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have just started to learn Regular Expressions and I think this can be done using regex, but not able to find a proper regex match. Here is the situation: I want to fill the Key in the array with the respective values, but make everything lowercase and underscore for space.

Example PHP array:

```
array('' => 'Red Apple',
      '' => 'Blue Sky',
      '' => 'Circle/Earth');
```

Output should be:

```
array('red_apple' => 'Red Apple',
      'blue_sky' => 'Blue Sky',
      'circle_earth' => 'Circle/Earth');
```

I was able to use strtolower() but getting stuck with using preg_replace(). Can I even do this with regex?

Thanks.

Comment: u can do this without using regex, consult string function in php manual

Answer (score 1):

As slier said, it can be done without preg_replace

Here is a snippet

`$new_key = strtolower(str_replace(array(' ', '/'), '_', $value)));`

Check http://php.net/str_replace
Quick introduction

str_replace(find, replace, value);

find can be an array containing common unwanted chars, such as array('-', '/', ' ', .. etc);

Answer (score 0):

[Confirmed working](http://codepad.viper-7.com/XLE51N):

```
$array = array(
    'Red Apple',
    'Blue Sky',
    'Circle/Earth'
);

function nice_keys($key) {
    return strtolower(str_replace(array(' ', '/'), '_', $key));
}

$clean_keys = array_map('nice_keys', $array);
$new_array = array_combine($clean_keys, $array);

print_r($new_array);
```

**Reference**:

- [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)
- [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)
- [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) and [`strtolower()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) to achieve this:

```
$key = strtolower(preg_replace(array('/[^a-z]+/i', '/\s/'), "_", $string));
```